# How can I update an "order by" field on a record when the row order in the PageBlockTable is changed?

Tags: apex, visualforce

visualforcepage:

```
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ob}" var="o" style="width:80%;" align="center" id="myTable">
    <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">S.NO</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputtext value="{!o.Order_numbering__c}" />
    </apex:column>
<apex:column ><button onClick="MoveUp.call(this);">&#8679;</button></apex:column>
<apex:column ><button onClick="MoveDown.call(this);">&#8681;</button></apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
```

Apex:

```
integer c=1;
        integer i=0;
   list<order_batch__c> oblist=[select Order_numbering__c,Or_clientpn__c from order_batch__c  where  Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c= : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') ];
    for(order_batch__c o : oblist){
     // if(o.Order_numbering__c==ob[i].Order_numbering__c)
       o.Order_numbering__c=c;
       c=c+1;
       i=i+1;
       }
      update oblist;
```

If I change the row order in pageblock table, I want to reset the numbering field Order_numbering__c back to 1,2,3 (the order of the rows in the table) and update the records.

Here is image shows my requirement
[image]

The up and down arrows are used to change the row order in the table. Whenever I did changes to move up and down arrow, how to check the before ordering, after ordering and number for that field `Order_numbering__c`?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. You could simply use a dynamic query to requery the data or:
2. or you could use data tables from datatables.net

or for a more crazy idea:
Off the top of my head you could do something like this. Is may not compile and needs work but you hopefully can get the idea

```
public class test_structure{


    public Static String row_to_sort;
    public Wrapper_Class[] wc {get;set;}

    public Wrapper_Class[] sort_row_1(){

        row_to_sort = 'row_1';
        return reindex(wc.sort());

    }

    public Wrapper_Class[] sort_row_2(){

        row_to_sort = 'row_1';
        return reindex(wc.sort());


    }

    private Wrapper_Class[] reindex(WrapperClass[] w){

        for(integer x=0;x<w.size();x++)
            w.idx = x;

        return w;

    }

    public class Wrapper_Class implements Comparable{

        public Object__c o {get;set;}
        public integer x {get;set;}


        public Wrapper_Class(){

            //Populate values
        }


        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            Wrapper_Class compareToObj = (Wrapper_Class)compareTo;

            //You may have to cast to be able to compare
            if (o.get(row_to_sort) == compareToObj.o.get(row_to_sort)) return 0;
            if (o.get(row_to_sort) > compareToObj.o.get(row_to_sort)) return 1;
            return -1;        
        }

    }



}
```

Use the wrapper to populate your page.
The arrows call the appropriate method based on the row
It set the static property to indicate the row name
then sorts the wrapper
then reindexes it so the numbers match up again.

Not very extensible at this point but it provides a starting point.

Also, you may need to find the type of the field you are sorting so you can cast the value as appropriate as I do not believe you can directly compare some objects to another.